# Toward Vim moves from conventional moves (<left> <right> <up> <down> <backspace>)

Tags: vim

I am not trying to play golf with my editor. I am just trying to improve my editing skills with vim.

Let's consider this piece of assembly that I would like to convert to C. In order to do it methodically, I want to make small changes iteratively line after line.

```
    dm(__abcd_bar_id + axis) = f4;
    f1 = dm(_abcd_foo_id + axis);
    f5 = f4 - f1;
```

The job with this example is:

1. Simplify the first line with `abcd_bar_id[axis] = f4`
2. Simplify the second line with `f1 = abcd_foo_id[axis]`
3. Replace f1 in the third line with the second line
4. Remove the second line

These steps are not negotiable. I know I can easily get rid of all my `dm(__variable + index)` with a regex like the one below but this is off topic.

```
:%s/dm\s*(\s*_\+\(\w\+\)\s\++\s\+\(\w\+\)\s*)/\1[\2]/g
```

So, to achieve these changes I traditionally do this:

<kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>
<kbd>▼</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>
<kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>◀</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>▼</kbd><kbd>End</kbd><kbd>◀</kbd><kbd>◀</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

And the result should be this:

```
abcd_bar_id[axis] = f4;        
f5 = f4 - abcd_foo_id[axis];
```

What saves me is I am quite fast hitting the same key multiple times. However I am sure I can be more productive if I use vi features

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>
<kbd>j</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>
<kbd>$</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>
<kbd>j</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

Well, this seems to me much more complicated for my brain because a pre-processing bain-time is needed before each keystrokes.

For instance if I want to move to `f1` I need to parse with my eyes if there is no other `1` on the way to `f1`.

I really feel I need years of training to be 'fluent' with vim.

So the questions are:

- How a vim guru will treat this example?
- Does a vim guru exist?

Comment: Are you aware of the possibiliity of using `q` to record the keystrokes in a macro for reuse?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Well, I use sometime `q` but I requires more brain-resources since I need to remember all the recorded macros. Perhaps It's a good approach, but I need to play a lot with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely don't consider myself vim guru, although I use it on the daily basis. Answering your second question first, probably there's somebody who can be treated as a guru, there are simply so many options and possibilities in vim, that everybody can have their own way of doing things. Moreover, because you can tailor vim to your needs, it's easy to simplify regular tasks, and those configurations may differ a lot. Also people who are considered gurus by me (like, for instance, [Derek Wyatt](http://derekwyatt.org/)) claim that have still much to learn about vim, so it can definitely take years to become one.

But don't be discouraged, it takes only some practise to start thinking vim-way, and your editing tasks will become much easier :)

Back to your example. First of all, I'd edit the first line with slightly less keystrokes:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

<kbd>i</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>

The difference isn't huge in terms of number of keystrokes, but it illustrates different approach. It allows, in my opinion, much less pre-processing, which is the problem you highlighted. I divided those keystrokes into sections to show you my thought process:

- <kbd>d</kbd>elete <kbd>t</kbd>ill <kbd>a</kbd>
- <kbd>f</kbd>ind <kbd>)</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd>eplace it with <kbd>]</kbd>
- <kbd>b</kbd>ack one word and <kbd>d</kbd>elete <kbd>T</kbd>ill (backwards) <kbd>d</kbd>
- <kbd>i</kbd>nsert <kbd>[</kbd>

I don't have to think much, when I apply those changes. You might think that this is counter-intuitive, that I jumped to `)` character first, but it was much easier for me to spot closing bracket than count words or 
hit <kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd> multiple times. Of course you might know the keystrokes but when you edit something you don't always remember all of them. This comes with practise and forcing yourself to use some of them (like <kbd>t</kbd>/<kbd>T</kbd>)
to put them firmly under your fingers. Also, print a cheat-sheet trying to make use of every key, until you'll learn it by heart. It won't take long ;)

As William already suggested in the comment, I'd also think about macro here. It's a powerful and easy-to-use tool, which can really automate your changes. 
I already know how to edit first line. In your example, I know that in the second step I'll be doing the same thing, but in slightly different location, so instead of editing first line, I instantly record a macro, but I have to make it universal 
for easier application. So I think about putting my cursor in proper location first, before making any changes. My macro would look like this:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>

<kbd>q</kbd>

Notice, that I added 3 keystrokes at the beginning (not counting qq, which starts recording macro to q register). That might look redundant in the first line, but it ensures proper location of the cursor before making any changes. 
That way I can easily apply this macro in the second line with <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Now, you have to replace this `f1` in the third line. You're still in the second line with your cursor, so you just yank with:
<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>

and then paste it to the third line:
<kbd>j</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

Using macros mith look like a redundant thing when you edit just 3 lines, but when you get used to making changes in a vim way, you'll really feel you're taking advantage of it's power.

When it comes to remembering recorded macros it's not that hard, you have to have the proper attitude. First of all, you record your macros to registers, so typing `:registers` will show you also your macros. Secondly, you can edit them, 
by pasting specific register, altering it and then saving to the same register. And then you can play it with `@[register_letter]`. And finally, don't get attached to specific macros. Save one or two, use them to make multiple changes at 
once and forget about them. And then record another one under the same letter. For example, if you realize that you have to make some repetitive change across the file, use `qq`, because it's fast and intuitive. After making changes you rarely 
need to play the same macro over again, because whole buffer is already in the right state. But if you know, that you'll need it, record next macro under another letter. If you'll get comfortable making changes intuitively vim way, so that 
they can easily be repeted, you'll find that's much easier to record another macro than trying to remember under which letter you recorded previous one.

I hope that this answer will convince you, that you don't need years of training to get fluent, but of course it won't happen overnight ;)